# Reading php scripts from php file

Tags: php, file-io

I have a file named "connection.php". I want to read the contents of this file to a string. I use fopen, and read functions for reading. But when I am reading I just got only last 2-3 lines on that file. That means no PHP scripts can read like echo, functions etc. How can I read the whole contents on that file?

Comment: Are you sure you want to read the file’s contents and not just “`include`” it?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('connection.php');
var_dump($str);
?>
```

note that if 'connection.php' contains `'<?php'` at the beginning, and you try to output it to a browser, you likely won't see anything unless you perform a "View Source".

Comment: I usually add a header('Content-Type: text/plain') at the top if I dump things like that.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [manual page of `fread`](http://php.net/fread) :

> `fread()` reads up to length  bytes from
>   the file pointer referenced by handle
>   . **Reading stops as soon as one of the
>   following conditions is met**:
>
> - length bytes have been read
> - EOF *(end of file)* is reached
> - a packet becomes available *(for network streams)*
> - **8192 bytes have been read** *(after opening userspace stream)*

If you want to read a whole file, you'll need to use some kind of loop, to read data until you reach the end of the file.

Or, as an alternate (probably easier), **you can use [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)**, which will get you the whole content of the file with only one function call.

Which means no need for `fopen` + multiple `fread` + `fclose` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your browser is hiding the content because it starts with '`<?php`'. You can try View Source in your web browser, or echo the contents in the following way:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('connection.php');
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlentities($contents);
echo "</pre>";
```